# Adal.js error AADSTS65001 with external API

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal.js

I have a Web API project. Authentication is wired against Azure AD per following code:

```
string tenant = "[tenant]";
string audience = "https://[tenant]/MyApp.Backend";

app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
  new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
  {
    Tenant = tenant,
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
      ValidAudience = audience
    }
  });
```

These are the properties of the app registration in Azure AD:

- Name: MyApp.Backend
- Application Type: Web app / API
- Application ID: 03486f5a-...
- URI: https://[tenant]/MyApp.Backend
- oauth2AllowImplicitFlow: false

I have a console client which is consuming the backend Web API. This console application is also registered in Azure AD:

- Name: MyApp.Frontend.Console
- Application Type: Native
- Application ID: 505f3928-...
- oauth2AllowImplicitFlow: false
- Delegated Permission: (MyAppBackend | Access MyApp.Backend)

Using this code I can login and get a access token which I can use to authenticate in the backend:

```
var ctx = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.windows.net/[tenant]/");
AuthenticationResult result = ctx.AcquireTokenAsync(
  "https://[tenant]/MyApp.Backend",
  "505f3928-...",
  new Uri("https://[tenant]/MyApp.Frontend.Console"),
  new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.RefreshSession)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

The problem starts with SPA. Following app registration describes the app:

- Name: MyApp.Frontend.Web
- Application Type: Web app / API
- Application ID: ea939554-...
- URI: https://[tenant]/c4e415b6-...
- oauth2AllowImplicitFlow: true
- Delegated Permission: (MyAppBackend | Access MyApp.Backend), (Microsoft Graph | Read users files)

The adal.js code looks like this:

```
window.config = {
  instance: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
  tenant: '[tenant]',
  clientId: 'ea939554-...',
  postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
  cacheLocation: 'localStorage', // enable this for IE, as sessionStorage does not work for localhost.
};

let authContext = new AuthenticationContext(config);
let isCallback = authContext.isCallback(window.location.hash);
if (isCallback) {
  authContext.handleWindowCallback();
}

let loginError = authContext.getLoginError();
if (isCallback && !loginError) {
  window.location = authContext._getItem(authContext.CONSTANTS.STORAGE.LOGIN_REQUEST);
} else {
  console.log('login error:', loginError);
}

loginButton.onclick = function () {
  authContext.login();
};

logoutButton.onclick = function () {
  authContext.logOut();
};

actionButton.onclick = function () {
  authContext.acquireToken('https://[tenant]/MyApp.Backend', function (error, token) {
    // this results in error AADSTS65001
  });
};
```

The token will not be fetched and the operation will result in the error **AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID 'ea939554-...'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.**

If I try to get a token for the Microsoft Graph then there is no error. The callback will be called with a valid token. So the app registration for the SPA is correct. The error/misconfiguration has to be somewhere in the MyApp.Backend registration but I don't know where. I have tried to set implicit flow in the backend manifest to true, inserted web frontend as knownClientApplications in the backend manifest. But it all results in the same error.

Who can help me?

Comment: Did you ever enter the username/password when you got this issue? I am trying to reproduce the issue by following the steps above however failed. And is it helpful to send the HTTP request directly using like `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id={ea939554-...}&redirect_uri={redirectURI}&resource={https://[tenant]/MyApp.Backend}`?

Comment: @Fei Xue This helped a bit. As the error message tells it has to do with the consent. The consent screen will not be shown when acquiring the token through adal.js. I have requested the URL directly and was able to consent. Afterwards adal.js was able to acquire the token for MyApp.Backend. This worked across different sessions and cleared local storage. Whenever a new user acquires a token the very first time it will result in the error until he has consented directly. Now the question is why can't adal.js consent?

Comment: Update on the issue: authContext.login() let me log in but never showed a consent screen. I have deleted the app MyApp.Frontend.Web from "Enterprise applications - All applications" in the portal. WARNNG: It is NOT the app registration! Now each user has to accept the consent screen when they authContext.login() the first time. I have built a MyApp.Frontend.Web.Two app registration. It works, no need to delete the app object. The problem disappeared. Strange.